# Customizing how Python's `copy` module treats my objects

Tags: python, copy, pickle

From the [`copy` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html):

> Classes can use the same interfaces to control copying that they use to control pickling.
>
> [...]
>
> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`

So which one is it? `__setstate__()` and `__getstate__()` that are used when pickling, or `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works as follows: if a class defines `__copy__`, that takes precedence for `copy.copy` purposes (and similarly `__deepcopy__` takes precedence for `copy.deepcopy` purposes). If these very specific special methods are not defined, then the same mechanisms as for pickling and unpickling are tested (this includes, but is not limited to, `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`; I've written more about this in my book "Python in a Nutshell" (which @ilfaraone quotes only partially).

Answer (score 1):

`__setstate__()` and `__getstate__()`.

Notice that the copy documentation says that they *can* use the same interface, but they don't necessarily have do so.

See [this excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=vpTAq4dnmuAC&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=pickle+setstate&source=bl&ots=AOP7A0L9BA&sig=qXdc-g4OWnbJWBbKI2EvX114qYE&hl=en&ei=Y9imSubHDojANoPioKQI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8#v=onepage&q=pickle%20setstate&f=false) from [Python in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596001886), or [this explanation](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/1999-June/005827.html) on the Python Mailing List.